# How to use IMPORTRANGE function

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I’m just having an issue. I need to IMPORTRANGE two Google sheet tables, but in the main source table is a filter turned on. I need to connect data from column "D" with name RM and categorize it according the column "A" with name Plant and from that column I need only data for "Cold SK".

As you can see, the rows are disordered now (it starts with number 2 and then number 9 etc.). Could someone please help me with how to use IMPORTRANGE function correctly in this case? Is it even possible?

[image: This is how table looks like]

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. The screenshot does not show disordered rows; it shows a sheet with filtered / hidden rows because a sheet/range filter is applied on column A. This kind of filter applies to the whole sheet. You could filter the data returned by formula by using functions like FILTER, QUERY or the newer functions based on LAMBDA, like reduce used in the answer to the target question shown in the close as duplicate notice. When asking for help with Google Sheets formulas, describe your spreadsheet, including the spreadsheet locale, include sample data as text, ...

Comment: ... both for the source / reference cells / ranges and the expected output. Include links to relevant questions and explain why they don't meet your needs.